# Let the random p-vector X have mean μ and covariance Σ. Show that E(x'Ax) = E[tr(xx'A)] = tr(ΣA) + μ'Aμ

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

E(x'Ax) = E[tr(xx'A)] = tr(ΣA) + μ'Aμ

The problem starts the proof for me so I carry on from,

E[tr(xx'A)] = tr(E[xx'A]) = tr(AE[xx'])

A theorem I'm familiar with tells me that E[xx'] = Σ + μμ'

Applying this gives me,

tr(AE[xx']) = tr(A(Σ + μμ')) = tr(AΣ + Aμμ') = tr(AΣ) + tr(Aμμ')

Which I suppose I can write as,

tr(AΣ) + tr(μ'Aμ)

But I don't see where I went wrong because I still have the trace of μ'Aμ...
It has been some time since I studied matricies so I'm quite rusty. I apologize if I'm making some foolish mistake. Thank you in advance for your help. I hope formatting isn't too bad?

Comment: is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. I read through the notations section which never mentioned A being symmetric. Nor did the problem mention A being symmetric.

Comment: So my method of doing it was correct except that I didn't realize the problem wanted me to show that E(x'Ax) = E[tr(xx'A)] (I thought they were just giving the first few steps!).

What I failed to see is that tr(μ'Aμ) = μ'Aμ because this is a 1xp vector times a pxp matrix times a px1 vector. Thus the trace is equal to the constant.

Comment: the formula you were using is for $xx^T$ instead of $x^Tx$. The dimensions don't match.

Comment: May you tell me where they don't match? I'm having trouble seeing it.

Comment: the former is a number whereas the latter is a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is symmetric, then it has Cholesky decomposition as $A=C^TC$. Let $y=Cx$, then 
$$E(x^T Ax)= E(y^Ty) = \sum_i E(y_i^2) = \sum_i (V(y_i) + E(y_i)^2) =  \DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr} \tr(\Sigma_y) + \mu_y^T\mu_y$$
where
$$\Sigma_y = E((y-Ey)(y-Ey)^T) = C\Sigma C^T,\quad \mu_y = C\mu$$
so
$$E(x^T Ax)=\tr(\color{red} C\Sigma {C^T}) + \mu^T A\mu = \tr(\Sigma C^T\color{red} C) + \mu^T A\mu = \tr(\Sigma A) + \mu^TA\mu.$$

If $A$ is not symmetric, apply the above to $B:=A^T + A$, and note that 
$$x^T A x = x^T A^T x, \quad \mu^T A\mu = \mu^TA^T\mu$$ 
(since they are just scalars) and that 
$$\tr(\Sigma A^T) = \tr(A^T\Sigma) = \tr((A^T\Sigma)^T) = \tr(\Sigma A)$$
since $\Sigma$ is symmetric. Now the same conclusion follows.